# PHP form button?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, button

Making a form in php, but the "Send" button looks like crap in the browser (its just a dark grey background with "send" on top) this has never happened before, and it was always a nice rounded button that "popped" of the screen, and was an obvious button!

Comment: how do i make the button look like a button again?

Comment: Can you post some code. Buttons are normally styled with css so you may need to add the css to your php form.

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with Chrome's developer tools, or Firebug for Firefox? In case not: Both have handy tools that let you "inspect" elements and see what CSS rules are applying. I would place my bet that there is a CSS rule that is too broad, and inadvertently applies to your input button.

Are you using a CSS reset file?  Those can occasionally be a pain. Either way, a *CSS Normalize* will probably be of help

http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0):

Make PHP generate a button in HTML, then set the  button to perform the PHP function you want when it's clicked.